# How to make an object not be affected by light?

Tags: light, shaders

I was to create a textured plane, and I want that plane to not be affected at all by light. Meaning no shading, and the render is exactly as bright as the texture I provided. Kind of like using the emission material but I don't want it to output any light either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easy in Blender Internal. Just enable Shadeless in material settings and voila.
For the same effect in Cycles, use this material node setup:
[image: material node setup]

Comment: This would also remove its shadow and presence in reflections, etc. - might want to combine some of the other Light Path types also.

Comment: thanks! probably the only good & easy to understand solution

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to just plug the image texture into the output node without a real shader like diffuse or principled bsdf in between. This would prevent the texture changing in any way (ie. light/shadows) because it doesn't have a real shader. Works for me!