# How to make certain objects not effected by a light source. Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light, lighting

I have a light in the scene and I want to make only one object in the scene unaffected by this light.  Preferably without compositing render layers.  Is this possible in cycles?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65221/how-to-make-an-object-not-be-affected-by-light

Comment: I can help if you share the blend file on: [blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)

Answer (score -1):

If there is only one light within the entire scene you could set the material that object has to shadeless.

Comment: No, there are about five lights in the scene.  I only want the emission of one to not affect one object.  There are multiple objects in the scene.