# Backlighting characters

Tags: cycles-render-engine, lighting

I'd like to add a backlight to my character in Cycles, but I don't want it to illuminate anything else—and I'd also like it to stay behind the character at all times, regardless of the camera's location. (This also should not rely on layers.)

I'd appreciate an answer answering this twofold request for an answer!

Comment: Cycles or blender internal? Moving camera? How does your set look light? With backlight, do you mean lighting rim? Can you add a reference image of what your lighting setup should look like?

Comment: As for being always behind your character simple parenting will do the job. But for lightning only one object without layers there is no go in Cycles. Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15337/how-do-i-make-objects-ignore-certain-light-sources and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/983/exclusive-lighting and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65221/how-to-make-an-object-not-be-affected-by-light

Comment: Bummer. Given that layers are going the way of the dodo in 2.8, I was really hoping that a way could present itself.

Comment: I have found some "hacky" way with another mesh as something like cage preventing from light spilling outside of it. But there are some cons at the moment. First of all, it's not working when another object is really close. Secondly indirect bounces aren't blocked. Also do you want to let other lights affect this character? Or should it have completely own lightning?

Comment: [Maybe helpful](https://imgur.com/a/l8pAxgo).

Comment: @LukeD I want it to be primarily affected by other lights, but to also have a slight backlight.