# Making an object unaffected by light

Tags: texturing, node-editor, lighting, shader-nodes

I have an 'images as plane' object and I'd like to make it so that it is 100% bright and not affected by any of the lights / shadows in the scene.

I'm using Cycles

I came across this post:
[How to make an object not be affected by light?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65221/how-to-make-an-object-not-be-affected-by-light)

...and have tried something similar based on the answer, but it just makes my object turn plane white and the image disappears.

I can't follow the exact solution as the linked answer because I dont appear to have an 'image texture' node due to me using an 'images as plane'

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Comment: What does it give if you plug your Image Texture into a Shader > Emission, that you plug into the Output?

Comment: Can you plug the image or color directly into the material output? Probably moonboots meant the same :)